# PANDAS data frame throws AttributeError when attemping to render plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm very much a beginner with PANDAS and matplotlib, so this might have an obvious answer that I'm not seeing.

I have a data frame, data_split_by_country, with three columns: user_country, progress_score, and percentage. I'm trying to plot the relationship between the progress score and the percentage split by the country column.

The `data_split_by_country` data frame looks something like this:

```
  user_country   progress_score   percentage  
 -------------- ---------------- ------------ 
  MX                          1          0.1  
  FR                          1          0.2  
  DE                          1          0.1  
  MX                          2          0.4  
  FR                          2         0.45  
  DE                          2          0.2  
  MX                          3          0.6  
  FR                          3         0.65  
  DE                          3          0.3  
  MX                          4          0.7  
  FR                          4          0.7  
  DE                          4          0.4  
  MX                          5         0.75  
  FR                          5         0.75  
  DE                          5          0.5  
  MX                          6          0.8  
  FR                          6         0.85  
  DE                          6         0.55  
  MX                          7         0.83  
  FR                          7         0.88  
  DE                          7         0.60  
  MX                          8         0.86  
  FR                          8          0.9  
  DE                          8         0.65  
  MX                          9         0.88  
  FR                          9         0.91  
  DE                          9         0.70  
  MX                         10          0.9  
  FR                         10         0.92  
  DE                         10         0.75
```

I'm trying to create this set of plots in PANDAS with the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_country(country='MX', civic = False, adjust_y_frames=False):

        text_string = "Country: " + country
        f, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=False, sharey=False, figsize=(12, 3))
        f.subplots_adjust(wspace=1)

        ax0.text(0.5, 0.5, text_string, fontsize=12, ha='center', va='center')
        ax0.axis('off')

        ax1.plot("progress_score", "percentage",
                           data=data_split_by_country.loc[(data.user_country==country)])

        f.show()

for country in ['MX', 'FR', 'DE']:
    plot_country(country)
```

However, when I run this code, I get the following error on the line attempting to plot `ax1`: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'user_country'`. As I understand it, the `loc` function should essentially filter the data frame, but maybe I'm mistaken.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**: So I thought that was the issue too, but when I change that line to `data=data_split_by_country.loc[(data_split_by_country.user_country==country)]`
, I get the following error:

```
/mnt/xarfuse/uid-32077/e6e06cc0-ns-4026531840/matplotlib/__init__.py in inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)
   1804                     # update the information about replace names and
   1805                     # label position
-> 1806                     _arg_names = positional_parameter_names(args, data)
   1807                     if (label_namer and  # we actually want a label here ...
   1808                             _arg_names and  # and we can find a label in *args

/mnt/xarfuse/uid-32077/e6e06cc0-ns-4026531840/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in _plot_args_replacer(args, data)
     66     elif len(args) == 2:
     67         # this can be two cases: x,y or y,c
---> 68         if not args[1] in data:
     69             # this is not in data, so just assume that it is something which
     70             # will not get replaced (color spec or array like).

TypeError: argument of type 'FutureCallable' is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the call to `ax1.plot()`, it looks like you meant to write "data_split_by_country.user_country" instead of "data.user_country"

```
data=data_split_by_country.loc[(data_split_by_country.user_country==country)]
```

Comment: Tried this, edited question above with new issue once the line becomes `data=data_split_by_country.loc[(data_split_by_country.user_country==country)]
`